# google.Load jQuery UI Specific CSS

Tags: jquery-ui, themes, jsapi

I am loading jQuery UI as

```
google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.6");
```

from the [Google CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI)
And I want the theme UI Darkness to be associated with it.
Any other methods other than

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Something like

```
google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.6","{theme: 'UI-Darkness'}");
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1348559/164552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far google loader doesn't support this syntax for jqueryui, you can check the documentation here.

http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/apis/loader/#GoogleLoad

I think refer to the link in a  tag is still the best way in your case.